# PgAdmin created objects fail to persist

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have a very puzzling issue with a single user - no other user anywhere has ever experienced anything like this. Using PgAdminIII 1.22.

If we create a table:

```
create table foo();
```

And then execute the identical command, it rightfully gives me the error:

```
ERROR:  relation "foo" already exists
```

However, if I do it a third time it succeeds. Every other transaction, it appears to completely remove the object, so hitting "F5" alternates between the object already exists error and a success message.

After the success message, the table is nowhere to be found. If I did this:

```
select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'foo';
```

The query would come up empty.

I am stumped. There is nothing unique about the user's profile or impacted schema, that I can tell. Can this be a client setting in PgAdmin?

Comment: is it not `create temp table foo();` ?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with many problems, we applied the universal fix to computer problems, and it resolved the issue.

The solution was to uninstall and re-install PgAdmin.

WEIRD.